# Does OWA let users change their AD passwords once their passwords are expired?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013, password-reset

We have a cloud active directory server which is running Exchange 2013. We have a lot of users with only exchange accounts and most of them will have their passwords expired in a few days,

I was wondering if the users can still reset their password though the OWA once their passwords are expired?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Users should be able to change their expired passwords using the OWA site.

In Exchange 2010, there was a registry `REG_DWORD` key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchange OWA\ChangeExpiredPasswordEnabled` that you had to set to `1`.  In 2013, this is a feature that's built in from the start.